# Fatal Exception: CALayerInvalidGeometry CALayer bounds contains NaN: [-14 nan; 375 0]

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer

Crashlytics integrated with my app reported a crash which says:

> CALayerInvalidGeometry:CALayer bounds contains NaN: [-14 nan; 375 0]

I am actually neither able to reproduce the crash nor I am able to identify any relevant information regarding the controller class or method where the crash is possibly occurring.
I have double checked all the maths included in my app and also went through several related questions over StackOverFlow but couldn't possibly found any solution.
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Indicate what all you have tried.  Without any relevant info, even if someone provides a solution, how will they know if you haven't tried it already (as you mentioned).

Comment: I re-verified that possibly none of the frame value are assigned negative values, or having a divide by zero type issue .

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko no issue with the down vote, but just want to tell that crashlytics reported a crash and there is no ViewController or methodor any specific line symbolized where the crash occurs, so it wasn't possible to put down code.

Answer (score 1):

These are extremely hard to spot but unfortunately this does look like some division-by-zero-like issue. First of all division by zero will not give you `NaN` but rather `inf` or `-inf`. The only way to get `NaN` with division by zero is to divide `0.0` by `0.0`. There are other ways of getting `NaN` like using `acos(2.0)` because `cos` is on interval [-1,1].

But then the best part is that any operation with `NaN` results into `NaN` which means the following:

```
let a: CGFloat = 0.0
let b: CGFloat = 0.0
let c: CGFloat = a/b

let frame = CGRect(x: 14.0, y: 30.0*c, width: 375.0, height: 0.0)
print(frame)
```

outputs `(14.0, nan, 375.0, 0.0)`. So even if you see no possible division by zero in `30.0*c` you mat still have division by zero in parameter `c`.

I know hitting an issue as this one is really painful. You could in your case overcome it by implementing a top level method like:

```
func CGRect(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) -> CoreGraphics.CGRect {
    return CoreGraphics.CGRect(x: x.isNaN ? 0.0 : x, y: y.isNaN ? 0.0 : y, width: width.isNaN ? 0.0 : width, height: height.isNaN ? 0.0 : height)
}
```

This will replace your `NaN` with `0.0` and most likely fix the crash. Still there is no way to tell what the results will be. You could also do the same and add some `if` statements in there and use a breakpoint to try and randomly reproduce the issue yourself. This way you might find more info on what is going on but you need to be able to reproduce the issue.